# GFCI for kitchen outlets far from faucet

Tags: electrical, kitchens, gfci

I gave a galley kitchen and a couple of outlets on the side opposite of the sink, so about 5-6 ft away from water. Do they need to be GFCI or just regular because they are at a distance? What is the usual distance limit within which GFCI is required?

Answer (score 4):

If the outlets serve a countertop then they need to be GFCI protected. The 6' distance  you refer to is for sinks not installed in kitchens.